# Como fazer um LIKE IN equivalente a PROCV

Tags: sql, sql-server, operador-like

Estou com a seguinte dúvida (abaixo é so um exemplo, pois não posso enviar as info verdadeira)
Quero fazer um `where` onde eu acho o nome da razao social pelo nome fantasia do estabelecimento, mas como os nomes são parecidos e não iguais não tem como ser por `IN`
Porem como esse `where` seria por uma subquery não consigo fazer pelo `LIKE` gostaria de saber como que deveria fazer.

Eu gostaria de saber o que é equivalente a um `LIKE IN`

Segue exemplos de querys abaixo:

**Exemplo query 1:**

```
SELECT RAZAO_SOCIAL FROM TABELA_01
```

sendo RAZAO_SOCIAL = SUPERMERCADO DA ANA

**Exemplo QUERY 2:**

```
SELECT NOME_FANTASIA FROM TABELA_02
 sendo NOME_FANTASIA = SUPER ANA
```

***O que eu quero***

```
SELECT RAZAO_SOCIAL FROM TABELA_01
WHERE RAZAO_SOCIAL **LIKE IN** (SELECT DISTINCT NOME_FANTASIA FROM TABELA_02)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT t1.razao_social,
       t2.nome_fantasia
  FROM tabela_01 t1
 INNER JOIN tabela_02 t2
    ON t2.nome_fantasia LIKE '%' + t1.razao_social + '%'
```

Comment: Se tiver alguma razão social "maliciosa" cadastrada que não tenha sido validada (_neutered_) quando foi inserida acho que tem chance de rolar uma SQL injection aqui, não? Aliás, já no momento da inserção.

Comment: @Piovezan não sei onde ele vai usar e como vai usar a query. Mas de qualquer forma não estou  usando `exec` na `razao_social`, não vejo como poderia ter chance.

Comment: Estou só levantando a lebre para ter em mente quem for implementar, realmente sem saber onde vai usar não dá pra saber. Mas quando penso numa string maliciosa me vem sempre à mente a ideia do Bobby Tables https://bobby-tables.com/img/xkcd.png que pode acontecer quando é chamada a execução da query externa.

Comment: @Sorack acho que desse jeito não pega se a fantasia for "SUPER ANA" onde a razão tiver "SUPERMERCADO DA ANA" acho que vai ter que quebrar por palavras e fazer o like nelas, algo assim o que acha?

Comment: @David não sei, mas dessa forma já tem uma resposta aqui no SO

Comment: @Sorack O risco que vejo de SQL injection é a string ser por exemplo `Whatever'; DROP TABLE tabela_01; --` e ter sido chamado um exec (é isso que executa queries?) na query externa. Vai executar três queries seguidas que estão separadas por ponto-e-vírgula, a primeira com um `LIKE %Whatever'`, a segunda que é um `DROP TABLE` e a terceira que é basicamente ignorada porque tem um indicador de comentário que serve para o banco ignorar tudo o que vier depois, no caso o restante da primeira query que é só o caracter `%`.

Comment: Tentou por similaridade de strings ? Já resolvi problema com isto.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2621739/similarity-between-strings-sql-server-2005